# Multiple Airport Extremes in bridge mode slow down over time as they are used

Tags: airport

I have two Airport Extremes connected to a Vigor2820 router which acts as the DCHP server. There is not any conflict with IP addresses.

The Airport Extremes are set to create a Roaming Network and work fine for while. After a period, can be hours or even a day or so the Internet Connection slows from 6 Mbps to virtually nothing. I have established that if I disconnect the Ethernet cable or restart one of the Airport Extremes the speed goes back to normal.

Both are set to bridge mode.

I have tried swapping the location of the bases but that doesn't make any difference.

How can I stabilize this setup so I don't have the gradual slowdown and the need to restart one of the Airport Extreme stations so often?

Comment: it happens with bought AE simultaneously?

Comment: I have this problem too. Do you found any solution? The Time capsule is a terrible shit when it is in the bridge mode...